# How do I set an array's values to be the first row of a worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba, while-loop

I am trying to create an array where values come from the first row of a worksheet, then print those values in another sheet.

I tried to read the first row of Sheet2, store each value in the array until I hit an empty cell, then print that array in the first row of Sheet3.

I'm getting a application defined error in the while loop where I am making sure the row is not equal to Null.

```
Private Sub createFormatSheet()

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")

        Dim myTags() As Variant
        Dim tag As Variant

        Dim rw As Range
        Dim i As Integer

        i = 1
        For Each rw In .Rows

            While rw(i, 1) <> Null
                myTags = Array(rw(i, 1))
                i = i + 1
            Wend

        Next rw

    End With

    With Worksheets("Sheet3")
        i = 1

        For Each tag In myTag
            .Cells(i, 1).Value = tag
        Next tag

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like you reference what cells you want to loop through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two approaches:

1. Using an array (you don't need to loop through the items
2. Directly using ranges, no array involved

Step through the code using `F8` and see what's going on

```
Private Sub createFormatSheet()

    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet

    Dim startRow As Long
    Dim endRow As Long

    Dim values As Variant

    Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")

    ' Array approach (no need to loop) source = column 1
    startRow = 1
    endRow = sourceSheet.Cells(startRow, 1).End(xlDown).Row

    values = sourceSheet.Range(sourceSheet.Cells(startRow, 1), sourceSheet.Cells(endRow, 1)).Value

    ' Target = column 1
    targetSheet.Cells(startRow, 1).Resize(endRow, 1).Value = values

    ' Direct range target column 2
    targetSheet.Cells(startRow, 2).Resize(endRow, 1).Value = sourceSheet.Range(sourceSheet.Cells(startRow, 1), sourceSheet.Cells(endRow, 1)).Value

End Sub
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help! However I do think I worded my question a little poorly as I was actually just trying to read the first row and not the first column. I changed the code you gave to do that and changed xlDown to xlToRight to read row 1 instead of column A
 `startRow = 1`
    `endRow = sourceSheet.Cells(startRow, 1).End(xlToRight).Column`

   `values = sourceSheet.Range(sourceSheet.Cells(1, startRow), sourceSheet.Cells(1, endRow)).Value`
   `targetSheet.Cells(startRow, 1).Resize(1, endRow).Value = values'`